# How to hide a directory within URL call

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, redirect

I don't think what I want can be done, but I thought I'd try here .. maybe someone can think outside the square for me...

I have installed wordpress on my domain at /wordpress.

I will eventually move it to / when it is finished and overwrite the existing content.

My problem is that in my posts, I have to reference images directly (i.e. /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/image.png)

My problem is that when I move wordpress to root, all of those images in the posts are going to be rendered invalid.

What I want to do is try and make a request for /wp-content/uploads/image.png find /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/image.png but I can't redirect everything to /wordpress because my existing site will disappear...

I'm thinking I need to install some type of internal media manager because I just can't see how this could work

Answer (score 2):

this might help u

```
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ http://www.newurl.com/$1 [R=3-1,L,NC)
```

u can get image name from old url and pass to new url..

Comment: That will take any image and redirect to new URL (meaning all existing images will now fail)

Comment: decide particulate url pattern for for new URL and Exclude that in HTACCES

Comment: Doesn't really help - If I use /wordpress/image - I will still need to duplicate all images in 2 directories (/wordpress/wp-content/uploads & /wp-content/uploads) - If I leave (/wordpress) out (in anticipation of the move), I will have to treat all images (existing and new) the same, ruining all existing images - I think I might use a symbolic link for /wp-content to redirect to /wordpress/wp-content at an os level - maybe that might work...

Comment: hi mate..this link might help you  http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.  I've seen that but was trying to figure out a way to reference URL's in a way that was transportable to avoid making any changes but I think you're right - that is probably my only option

Comment: I decided to use a shortcode - when calling an image, I use a shortcode to add the extra directory - this way, when I migrate - I make 1 change in 1 spot to fix all

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting is not really a solution here, IMO it just creates additional load, you should do a database wide search and replace of all referenced URLs after you move.

I recommend using searchreplacedb2 - I've been using it for years and it works great for me- 
http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Search **yourdomain.com/wordpress**

Replace **yourdomain.com**